# sails redirecting to https on localhost

Tags: sails.js

I have one live project, which I run on my localhost for development. As the live site is on HTTPS. So, after cloning on local, I comment https code. But still, when I open http://localhost:1337 it redirects me to https://localhost:1337 due to which it's not working on localhost. Even `sails lift` output is showing HTTP URL on the console.

[sails lift output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nITKd.png)

Comment: Does it work in a 'private tab' or different browser? If you tried to load the localhost version in your browser before removing whatever code redirects to https your browser may have cached/remembered that it should redirect to https.

Comment: Have you checked bootstrap.js and http.js files?

Comment: Make sure this isn't an issue with your browser.  You may have to clear your history or ensure a plugin is not interfering

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your valuable input. It is resolved now.
Actually, issue was, actually in some file, there was javascript redirection, which was redirecting HTTP to HTTPS for the whole site.